# Does MarkLogic replicas forests will also take participate in search queries

Tags: performance, search, marklogic, replicate

We have configured MarkLogic as follows

```
Host 1:    master_forest_01     replica_forest_03
Host 2:    master_forest_02     replica_forest_01
Host 3:    master_forest_03     replica_forest_02
```

Everything is working fine.

Master forests are in "open" state and replicas are in "sync replicating" state

As far as i know, only forests with open state will participate in search queries, and with "sync replicating" will wait for failover scneario

I want to confirm if this assumption is right or not.
Or 
it takes participation to improve performance?

Can we just add Host4 with only replicas forest, will this boost performance? 
I mean we want to know, what more to do to improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replica forests (setup for HA) will not participate in search. They are available to seamlessly handle fail-over.

If you think adding another forest will improve performance, you should do that as a master forest with a replica setup).

Having said that, measure against your SLA in a perf environment before you think you need more forests. Simply adding forests (for parallelization) without measuring against your SLAs may not help you.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for your quick reply. OK. understood. Do you have any link with benchmark available from MarkLogic on data size, No. of forests, VM configuration, response time etc. ? This will be really helpful to define performance requirements accordingly.

Comment: This document may provide some guidance - https://developer.marklogic.com/media/white-paper/hardware-reference-arch-das.pdf. But note that this is 3 years old. Some things will have changed. But use it as a starting point and measure in a performance environment. Good luck.